rearrange bars in ggplot
I want to rearrange the bars in the following graph. i want to show CT and HS bars side by side , for example first 1DAS CT and HS bar then 15DAS CT and HS bar and so on. I am using the following code
ggplot(data, aes(x = Genotype, y = Pn, fill = DAS)) +
  geom_col_pattern(aes(pattern = Treatment), pattern_color = '#00000050',
                   position = position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.5, 
                   color = 'gray50',
                   pattern_angle = 45, pattern_spacing = 0.02) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = c('none', 'stripe'),
                       guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = 'white'))
  ) +
  scale_fill_brewer('Species', palette = 'Pastel2', 
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = 'none'))
  ) + 
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(face = "bold"),
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))

and i got this graph in which for each genotype first it showed CT bars and then for HS bars.


Does this answer your question? Arrangement of bars with ggplot2 / ggpattern

Ordering can ultimately be controlled by setting an appropriate group aesthetic.
Here I make up some data similar to yours and then do some factoring to control sort order. After sorting I compute a grp_ord column indicating the desired order and pass it to the aes(group = grp_ord) aesthetic.
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

# data similar to yours
data <- expand.grid(
  genotype = c("BGB001", "BGB011"),
  das = c("1DAS", "15DAS", "35DAS"),
  treatment = c("CT", "HS")
) %>%
  mutate(pn = runif(12, 0, 15))

data %>%
  # set factor levels to control ordering
  mutate(
    genotype = factor(genotype, levels = c("BGB001", "BGB011")),
    das = factor(das, levels = c("1DAS", "15DAS", "35DAS")),
    treatment = factor(treatment, levels = c("CT", "HS"))
  ) %>%
  # order as desired
  arrange(genotype, das, treatment) %>%
  # compute group factor with desired order
  mutate(grp_ord = interaction(genotype, das, treatment),
         grp_ord = fct_inorder(grp_ord)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = genotype,
    y = pn,
    fill = das,
    group = grp_ord
  )) +
  geom_col_pattern(
    aes(pattern = treatment),
    pattern_color = '#00000050',
    position = position_dodge(0.7),
    width = 0.5,
    color = 'gray50',
    pattern_angle = 45,
    pattern_spacing = 0.02
  )


Created on 2024-05-21 with reprex v2.1.0
